# When using a tax treaty tie breaker, who makes the decision?

Tags: taxes, international

Many tax treaties between countries contain a tie breaker clause to avoid double taxation that resembles this:

If an individual is a tax resident of both countries:

- He will be deemed resident of the country where he has a permanent home.
- If he has a permanent home in both countries, he'll be deemed a resident of the country where his center of vital interests is closest.
- If the previous test is inconclusive, he'll be deemed resident of the country where he has his habitual abode.
- If the previous test is inconclusive, he'll be deemed resident of the country where he's a national.

My question is, things like determining the "center of vital interests" are somewhat subjective. Usually who makes the decision? Does the individual need to contact both countries tax agencies to get an opinion?

Comment: I assume that there's questions in the tax forms that try to assess that.